# Convert string which is a number in string form into integer number

Tags: python, string, integer

We can convert string into integer if given string is a number but what if its a string whose meaning is a number how we can convert it

Ex.
A= "one"

I know that string 'one' means 1 in integer form but how I can convert it into 1

And its starting
Variable A can contain number with more than one digit

Please help!!!!
Thanks in advance

Comment: please make an attempt at solving the problem and share any code and what is not working for you

Comment: Use a dictionary; I don't think there is a faster way to do it.

Comment: Try https://pypi.org/project/word2number/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there are packages that do this automatically, but you could make your own mapping...

```
name_num_map = {"ZERO":0, "ONE":1}
num_name = "One"
num = name_num_map[num_name.upper()]
```

How to deal with more than one digit turns into a parsing / grammar question. A simple solution is to assume that all words (or at least what regular expressions think is a word) make up the number in regular decimal ranking order. So, you'd get

```
import re

name_num_map = {"ZERO":0, "ONE":1} # and etc...

def numerizer(s):
    digits = [name_num_map[name.upper()] for name in re.findall(r"\w+", s)]
    rank = 1
    val = 0
    while digits:
        val += digits.pop() * rank
        rank *= 10
    return val

num = numerizer("one zero, one")
print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution will be to use [word2number](https://pypi.org/project/word2number/)

```
$ pip install word2number
$ python
>>> from word2number import w2n
>>> w2n.word_to_num("one")
1
>>> w2n.word_to_num("nine thousand")
9000
>>> A = "one"
>>> w2n.word_to_num(A)
1
```